# how to reset dropdown selected index serverside value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

problem is I have a `date` text box and a `shifts` drop down. When I select a date and shift I get the list of employees. dropdown has a `onSelectedIndexChanged` event, so employee list will be populate only if we change shifts. So for date chage I have added ajavascript to reset `shift dropdown` to `0` index. therefore every time when you change the date you have to select the shift too and the selectindex change event will be fired.**BUT** `the problem is when I reset shifts dropdown from javascript it is done only in client side not in server side.So if I select dropdownt to the previous value it doesn't fire the change event but for other values it works fine`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSelectDate" runat="server" CssClass="inputAddRes" onchange="javascript:return ResetShifts();"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShifts" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlShifts_SelectedIndexChanged"                                     runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Text="Morning" Value="1"/>
<asp:ListItem Text="Evening" Value="2"/>
<asp:ListItem Text="Night" Value="3"/>
</asp:DropDownList>

function ResetShifts() {
        document.getElementById('<%= ddlShifts.ClientID %>').selectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call the select onchange event manually

```
 document.getElementById('<%= ddlShifts.ClientID %>').onchange();
```